# iOS and xcode: how long of a string can be stored in NSUserDefault?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I would like to store a long string (several paragraphs of written text) as part of a key:value pair using xcode's NSUserDefaults. Is this possible? Does anyone know the maximum length string I can safely save in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's only the device limit, no any limits for NSUserDefaults.

Comment: If that is the case, I would be able to store megabytes of text information as a single string? I was taught that I must use the plist file or core data for anything larger than a few words. What do you think about this?

Comment: @jake9115 I would suggest to use core date for this. it's a bit unusual to use NSUserDefaults to store megabytes of text. but there are not limits, so it's up to you

Comment: @Dimitry, Would it be reasonable to store a few paragraphs? Are there any dangers involved?

Comment: @jake9115 I can't imagine any dangers, but probably Core Data will be faster, if it's important for you. anyway you can change it, if you have any performance problems.

Comment: You won't be able to control how long the data remains in memory, which may cause issues on low-ram iOS devices.

Comment: Another question... How long does NSUserDefaults data persist? Will it stay around after hard restart? Is there anything the user could do to delete the NSUserDefaults accidentally, short of deleting the app?

Comment: It's permanent unless the app is deleted or the data is removed via the API

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [discussion on the Apple Support Community forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1763096?start=0&tstart=0) that addresses your question.

You should take into consideration best practices for storing large amounts of data.  In this case, you're probably better off utilizing Core Data.  `NSUserDefaults` isn't intended for storing large amounts of information.

I believe Core Data offers quicker performance when saving/loading too - however, I've not independently confirmed this.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is very fast to read from, but caches pretty aggressively, and always writes out the whole domain (when it writes at all; it does do write coalescing). These two aspects are why it's better suites to small amounts of data.